# Non-Web application in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have just started learning Spring-Boot. I have created simple Spring-Boot web-application using gradle. BUT I want a non-web application project where I can run all code from PSVM and also I have to remove tomcat dependency. I searched about it but got no example.

What is needed to make the Spring Boot application context start as a non-web application context?

Comment: This is not a request for recommendations. The OP is misguided as to how answers should be supplied in SO, but the question is a genuine question. Editing to clarify.

Comment: Although it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945658/what-is-the-official-spring-boot-way-to-start-a-simple-non-web-based-java-applic

Answer (score 13):

Spring Boot provides some example applications: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples. The simple command line sample would be this one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple

From the referenced example project, the key is for the main class to implement `CommandLineRunner` - here is the code from the example project:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleSimpleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        // ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleSimpleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have the answer now. SpringBoot provides an interface named "CommandLineRunner". we can extend it and override its "run" method to define our class to execute.